How do I create a homebrew feat on D&D Beyond that allows using intelligence instead of strength for attack and damage?
I am creating a genius fighter who is on track to becoming a general. He uses Int instead of Str for melee attack and damage and is has learnt to take advantage of weaknesses in battle to strike true and time attacks perfectly.
I am trying to create a feat to allow the character to use Int for attack and damage rather than adjusting each weapon, but can't get it to work. Can someone please offer step by step what to select in all the dropdowns. Selecting for example Melee Weapon Attack - Slashing + Primary Stat = Int doesn't add int bonus to a long sword attacks to hit bonus for example.
The feat should also grant +1 bonus to intelligence.

"Replace Weapon Ability" sounds closer, but I can't get that to do anything either. You can customize each weapon's Attack action in the Actions list, but that must be done for each and won't change with the character's INT score.

According to https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/dungeons-dragons-discussion/homebrew-house-rules/76031-demystifying-homebrew-updated-with-pact-hex?srsltid=AfmBOorftDxYm3Cw9RFMA31Z5WeOY_6F1m69NoGUmI6cmzAii7zqUicf#c4 , the "Melee Weapon Attack" modifier doesn't work and "Replace Weapon Ability" only works with a pact weapon or hex weapon.

What is your archetype? Because it feels like it would be class features like Battle Master maneuvers or Eldritch Knight cantrips that account for your genius.

My archetype is battle master.(side note: Never got an answer from dnd beyond).

It looks like you've accidentally made two accounts. You should go through the process of getting them merged

https://www.reddit.com/r/dndbeyond/comments/13y92ug/homebrew_how_to_replace_a_weapons_attack_and/ This is the closest you'll find.  It only applies to magic weapons. It will work, for that use case (this is essentially a Strixhaven feat)
